# Show jQuery UI validation in tooltip

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

As soon I've started using MVC I couldn't realize how to display correct error validation in a tooltip.

For an instance:

```
$(document).tooltip({
     items: ".input-validation-error",
     content: function() {
           return $(this).attr('data-val-required');
     }
});
```

It shows just "data-val-required" message. How can I make it dynamically to show the correct error that has occured? There's any libray/framework in JS to implement it?

Comment: im surprised you want the validation in a tool tip.  Don't you want to display the validation on the page, not where they have to mouse over it to see it?

Comment: @MattBodily My layout is not designed to support message errors. My chance is to display it in a tooltip. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

How we set up our validation is to put attributes on the fields that have validation (in the model)

```
[Required]
public string Field { get; set; }
```

then on the view use the validation helpers.  At the top

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

and generally below each field

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Field, "*")
```

we like to use asterisk next to the field and have the message show in the summary at the top.  you can replace that with a message if you would like.  To trigger server side do a post back and in the post action check

```
ModelState.IsValid()
```

if not then send it back and the messages will show.  From your code it looks like you are wanting something fired with Jquery which you can do with

```
if($('form').valid()){
    //something here,  ajax call maybe when all forms are valid
}
```

this will trigger the validation for you on the client side.  It will highlight the fields red and a summary of all of the invalid fields will show at the top.  Hopefully this helps.